# how to install django on cpanel

Tags: django, ftp, cpanel

What directory do I need to put the files in?
I tried public_html but when I put the files there and clicked on setup.py, it didn't start the script.

Comment: I can not write a detailed answer as this question is closed but this step by step guide will help [Deploy Django app on Shared Hosting using CPanel](https://blog.umersoftwares.com/2019/09/django-shared-hosting.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probably not the best thing to run Django application on cPanel (shared hosting) because of the following:

- Most shared hosting providers do not allow you to install custom libraries which need to be compiled. You can still however create [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and `pip` install packages into as long as they do not require anything to be compiled (e.g. Django)
- Performance. In my experience it is possible to deploy a simple Django application on shared hosting however it is not very reliable and does not perform very well.

However it is not to say that it is impossible. These rough steps should be accurate enough to guide you to the right path. I haven't done this is a while so there might be mistakes.

- First you have to have SSH access
- Login into your account and create virtualenv for your django project

  ```
  $ cd ~
  $ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz
  $ tar -zxvf virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz
  $ python virtualenv-1.9.1/virtualenv.py djangovevn
  ```
- Add virtualenv bin folder to the path (inside `.bash_profile`)

  ```
  export PATH="/home/<username>/djangovenv/bin:$PATH" # inside .bash_profile

  # activate .bash_profile
  $ source .bash_profile
  ```
- Then `pip` install everything your project requires. Make sure to activate virtualenv first

  ```
  $ source ~/djangovevn/bin/activate
  $ pip install django
  ```
- Configure Django as usual. Make sure `DEBUG` is `False`
- Inside `public_html` create `index.fcgi`. Make sure to use the virtualenv Python path. Django docs about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache).

  ```
  !/home/<username>/djangovenv/bin/python
  import sys, os

  # add projects directory to the path so that
  # settings from the project can be imported
  sys.path.insert(0, "/home/<username>/path/to/project")

  # Switch to the directory of your project #
  os.chdir("/home/<username>/path/to/project")

  # Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable #
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.settings"


  # Run the fastcgi instance #
  from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
  runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
  ```
- Configure the `index.fcgi` in `public_html/.htaccess`

  ```
  AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
  ```
- Activate the fastcgi

  ```
  $ cd ~/public_html
  $ touch index.fcgi
  $ chmod 0755 .htaccess
  $ chmod 0755 index.fcgi
  ```
- All Done!

However this method will drive you crazy very fast. Apache is not meant for this and this method is not popular for a reason. This should be good enough in the beginning however as you will get more advanced deploying Django app, you should consider using some other hosting provider which allows for more flexibility such as WebFaction or heroku.

Comment: Note that there is a hash missing at the start of the `index.fcgi` file. Also, for anyone finding this now, the `django.core.servers.fastcgi` module was removed from Django in version 1.9 (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471471)).

Answer (score 0):

Django is a framework that runs in a Python instance, and not as a set of files that are served from a web server, like HTML or PHP. Most likely you will need another hosting provider that hosts web *applications* like [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Comment: That is not true. There is FastCGI...

Comment: Yes, but going this route usually ends in massive amounts of time being spent to get it running it that even happens. +1 for not being an affiliate link :)