# How to Run a shell script with no linux server...?

Tags: sh, lamp

I have a .sh file, which when run, downloads database info, html pages, etc... on my IP address. So it is basically using LAMP to make a website. However, the server I use is very unreliable. Is there a way to, per say, run the .sh script in CPanel or WHM online? They are domain companies, and so I thought I could download my .sh file there, so that my site is already set up.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: What exactly does the script do? It sets up a LAMP stack? Assembles a static website? It is certainly possible to run a shellscript without a Linux machine, but depending on what it is the script does, and what you are trying to achieve, it may not make sense to do so. https://www.cygwin.com/ can be used to provde a *nix-y shell and environment on older Windows machines, and Microsoft themsevles have a bash shell environment available for Windows 10: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10. If you are on a Mac, you can simply open a terminal, since OSX includes a *nix shell.

Comment: If you would like to see the .sh script itself, here it is: https://github.com/dlareau/puzzlehunt_server/blob/generic/easy_setup.sh

Comment: This script appears to set up an environment for an install a Django web application. You could do this locally on a desktop machine if you want a local development server, but I wouldn't recommend running a production web service that way.  If you are just looking for a way to run a Django server on a cPanel server, it does seem that it isn't totally impossible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625151/how-to-install-django-on-cpanel provides an overview of what must be done. That said, this is not going to be an easy or pleasant undertaking, and I would recommend against it.